# MySQL join: How to get result from one table even if secon table has no matching data

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have two tables with 'articles' and 'tags' I am trying to fetch articles and their corresponding tags, with this code:

```
       SELECT b.id, b.title, b.content, b.slug, b.created_at, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as tags
FROM blogs b INNER JOIN 
     tags t
     ON b.id = t.blog_id
GROUP BY b.id, b.title;
```

The problem is that if an blogs has no tag, then I get no blogs, instead of getting the blog with no tags, how is this achievable

Comment: Use left join instead of inner join.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left join`:

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, b.content, b.slug, b.created_at, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as tags
FROM blogs b LEFT JOIN 
     tags t
     ON b.id = t.blog_id
GROUP BY b.id;
```

Normally, selecting a bunch of columns with a `GROUP BY` would be bad style.  However, `blogs.id` is (presumably) unique in `blogs`, so this is the one case where selecting other columns from `blogs` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is **Left outer Join**.

```
select  b.id,b.title,b.content,b.slug,b.created_at,GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as tags 
from
blogs b left join tags t 
on b.id = t.blog_id 
group by b.id,b.title;
```